# Ruby - Timeout when the Queue is not decreasing

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a program that uses multiple threads and a queue. The threads are decreasing the queue (in case the data that was acted on was successful processed) but there are certain items (which I don't know up-front) which simply cannot be decreased.

So say I have a queue of size 700, it goes down to 670, 340, 20...and then it gets stuck there.

Is there some way to tell Ruby to do something in case the queue size stays the same for more than X seconds?

Comment: I guess you can have a dedicated thread that checks the queue size every X seconds, and makes sure it has less items than the last check...

Comment: Makes sense. So if the items are the same, then terminate all threads, the entire program. How would you do that?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-exit

Comment: No, I mean, how would you terminate all threads with something like exit? Will (Thread.list - Thread.current) { |t| t.exit } work?

Comment: It should (I would also subtract `Thread.main`...)